# I am not seeing mp3 files name in my Android recycler view, instead I am seeing their links

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

In my Android recycler view I have not seeing my mp3 file-name which I suppose retrieve from firebase real-time DB. Instead of that I am seeing that mp3 link. How to correct this?

I have uploaded some mp3 files in firebase file storage, those mp3 files links are added in my Firebase real-time DB. When I retrieved file and its description in Android recycler view, I am getting mp3 file's link. But not file name.

XML code of card view having 2 text views in it:

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#b7c8e9"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="song_file_name"
            android:id="@+id/song_name"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="song_description"
            android:id="@+id/song_desc"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

View holder java code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SongViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public SongViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setDetails(Context ctx, String song, String description){
        TextView mSongTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.song_name);
        TextView mSongDescTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.song_desc);

        mSongTv.setText(song);
        mSongDescTv.setText(description);
    }

}
```

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SongModel, SongViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SongModel, SongViewHolder>(
                        SongModel.class,
                        R.layout.song_row,
                        SongViewHolder.class,
                        mRef
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(SongViewHolder viewHolder, SongModel model, int position) {

                        viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getSong(), model.getDescription());
                    }
                };
        mrecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
```

I also created getters setters for song and description field.

I need to display mp3 song name. Not its link, because later I need to click them and play. But I am seeing mp3 links in my recycler view output.

[DB Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RATFN.png)

[Output coming with files link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWl9i.png)

Comment: Hello Shivaraj Sajjan, you need to store the song's name when you want to store the data (description and song) . What I mean is when you want to store data, you need to include the song's name too.

Comment: You see both song name and url, right? What's the problem? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I just want list of mp3 songs with their original file names. So that I can add onclick listener and media player to play those songs further.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. The song field in your database has the song URL. So the URL is displayed in your recyclerView. You can add the metadata of your mp3 such as name artist etc to your database too. After that, you can display them as you want.

Comment: I just want list of mp3 songs with their original file names. So that I can add onclick listener and media player to play those songs further